# Methyl iodide in water

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

Iodide being a good leaving group and water being quite a weak $\ce{Nu-}$, does  $\ce{CH3I}$ undergo $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction? I was taught that whenever a protic solvent which can ionize the halide is present, $\ce{C+}$ will form and any type of $\ce{Nu-}$ will attack (both weak/strong).

Also, if not, is there any other reagent which brings about $\mathrm{S_N1}$ pathway?

Comment: Methyl generally does not participate in Sn1 reactions because the transition state for making a methyl cation is quite high in energy. You might be able to force it with something like antimony hexafluoride to rip off the iodide.

Comment: If you try to propose a mechanism involving CH3+, you *will* get called out: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/364/6440/eaax7083/

Answer (score 4):

Methyl iodide does not undergo $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions. The methyl carbocation is so unstable that there is virtually zero possibility of unimolecular dissociation:

$$\ce{CH3I \not\to \color{red}{CH3+} + I- }$$

For all intents and purposes the SN1 pathway is only operable for secondary and tertiary halides.